# Sign Table with Bullets and Circles

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-tab

I'm creating a sign table,

```
\xpatchcmd{\tkzTabLine}{$0$}{$\bullet$}{}{}
\tikzset{t style/.style={style=dashed}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[lgt=1,espcl=1,deltacl=0]
  { /.8, N /.8, D /.8,  /.8, /.8}
  {,$-1$,$0$,$1$,}
\tkzTabLine {,+,z,-,t,-,z,+}
\tkzTabLine {,+,t,+,z,-,t,+}
\tkzTabLine {,-,t,+,t,-,t,+}
\tkzTabLine {,\cap,t,\cup,t,\cap,t,\cup}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

I would like to have \circ, in the second row (the one with D), instead of the bullet.
I understood that the first row

```
\xpatchcmd{\tkzTabLine}{$0$}{$\bullet$}{}{}
```

is used to add those bullets onto the column lines according to the syntax

```
\xpatchcmd{command}{search}{replace}{success}{failure}
```

I've tried to add

```
\xpatchcmd{\tkzTabLine}{$1$}{$\circ$}{}{}
```

but I don't know what to write in the table instead of "z".

Is it possible to add another symbol? Thank you

PS. don't mind the actual signs inside

Comment: If you want to place `\circ` instead of bullets here, you don't have to anything else that use `\xpatchcmd{\tkzTabLine}{$1$}{$\circ$}{}{}`. It works nicely. So what is the point in your question? And not related but please post a full compilable MWE so that we don't have to guess what package you load.

Comment: have a look at my answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/598803/140722

Comment: After re-reading your question, it seems that I missed something that may be important. You want to keep the bullets for the zeros AND add some `\circ`s elsewhere? But for what purpose and where exactly? On the dashed lines? Into some cells? Anyway, I gave you an answer that allows to put anything anywhere into the table, feel free to adapt and/or to ask for improvements.

Comment: @SebGlav yep you understood well, I wanted to keep both the bullets and the circle, and your answer is perfect. By the way, I wanted both because the bullet stands for "number included" (for example x >= 5) while the circle stands for "number not included" (x>5). Studying the sign of a function (in reality here is f''(x) ) such as N/D >=0, the first row in the table is N, the second D, and the third is the sign of N/D. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tkz-tab` package, you can customize almost everything with a bit of work. And you can also have access to every node. Just add `help` in your `\tkzTabInit` declaration.

```
\tkzTabInit[lgt=1,espcl=1,deltacl=0,help]
```

You get this:
[image: tkztabhelp]

Now, you can draw wherever you want, whatever you want.
Say you want to add a red circle between nodes `N22` and `N23`, you just have to write something like:

```
\path (N22) -- (N23) node[red,midway,inner sep=2pt,draw,circle,fill=white]{};
```

which produces (after deleting the `help` option):
[image: tkztab2]

Note that I already used your `xpatch` trick to replace the bullet by a `\circ`, which worked nicely.